# Get specific directory of included project in gitlab-ci

Tags: deployment, ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My **gitlab-ci.yaml**:

```
stages:
  - linter
  - build
  - deploy

include:
  - project: 'infrastructure/ansible-repository'
    ref: '1.0.0'
    file: '/project-pipeline.yml'
```

In the **project-pipeline.yml** there's a `before_script:` where I need to access a directory from the infrastructure/ansible-repository. At the moment I `git clone` the whole repository.

My Question: is there an include for a directory or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a way to download a sub directory from a remote repository. Based on which repository hosting platform (E.g. GitLab, GitHub, BitBucket and ...) you used Or your interaction with that directory there are many solutions.
 Such as `git archive`, `git clone --filter`, `svn` tool, `wget`, **sparse checkout** and so on, which all 
described in this helpful post:

[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)